# some of the iOS apps does not shows action extension feature in iOS8 devices

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

> Basically when i do open in functionality in other apps basically it
>   will show tow options 1. open-in 2. extensions. But i am seeing some
>   of the apps not showing the other apps action extension feature. I do
>   not know how they are hiding it?. Or they doing something else to do
>   not show the other apps extensions other than iOS defaults action
>   extensions?.

**Example:**

> YES: Mailbox, Dropbox, Box etc. - these app was able to show the other
>   apps action extension
>
> NO: Evernote, Acompli, Zoho Docs - - these app does not shows the
>   other apps action extension.

Any idea? why evernote and Zoho not showing the other apps action extension feature?. Is there something they need to do on their side or i need to do on my side to make it show?.

Any help that might be really appreciated.

screenshots attached.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Action and Share extensions have an activation rule, which is stored as `NSExtensionActivationRule` in their Info.plist. These extensions only appear if the host app is sharing data that matches the activation rule. For example, if an app shares images and the extension can only handle text, the extension will not be displayed as an option in that app.